# How can I convert a pointer/address as an integer to a struct?

Tags: winapi, rust

[winapi](https://docs.rs/winapi/latest/winapi/) is a crate with raw FFI bindings to the Windows API.

The argument `lParam` in the [`LowLevelMouseProc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644986(v=vs.85)) callback function is "a pointer to an `MSLLHOOKSTRUCT` structure". When I log it, it is just a "random" number. I understand that pointers are addresses to the memory, but I don't fully understand how to convert an address as an `isize` (which `lParam` seems to be) to the [`MSLLHOOKSTRUCT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-msllhookstruct) `winapi::um::winuser::MSLHOOKSTRUCT` struct.

Comment: FYI, the Windows API is C, not C++. But in any case your question seems to only pertain to Rust and its pointer-converting facilities.

Comment: And there is no `LowLevelMouseProc` in the docs for the `winapi` crate.

Comment: @Jmb, If it's like the actual winapi, the item you're looking for is probably `HOOKPROC` or `SetWindowsHookEx`. The name is more just illustrative to differentiate this class of callback from others such as a keyboard one that all fit into the same callback parameter on `SetWindowsHookEx`, but have different rules for how to interpret the arguments.

Comment: The [winapi](https://crates.io/crates/winapi) crate is stale at this time and hasn't received an update in more than a year. Consider using the [windows](https://crates.io/crates/windows) crate instead. It's not going to change the immediate challenge but at least it's regularly updated.